# SQL Server 2008 - Trying to edit dates - Syntax Error?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax-error

I have a database that has startDate and endDate. I am trying to run this simple script to find and replace certain dates. Here is my script:

```
SET startDate = '2012-10-11 07:00'
AND
endDate = '2012-10-13 20:00'

where startDate = '2012-10-12 07:00'
AND
endDate = '2012-10-14 20:00'
```

I run it and receive this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '='.: SET startDate => '2012-10-11 07:00' AND endDate = '2012-10-13 20:00' where startDate = '2012-10-12 07:00' AND endDate = '2012-10-14 20:00'
```

I really have no idea why it's not running correctly, but hopefully one of you clever bod's here will be able to point out my incredibly dumb mistake!

Here's hoping! =0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to separate your columns to update with a comma rather than `AND`:

```
UPDATE  YourTable
SET     startDate = '2012-10-11 07:00',
        endDate = '2012-10-13 20:00' 
WHERE   startDate = '2012-10-12 07:00' 
AND     endDate = '2012-10-14 20:00'
```

You should also use a culture insensitive date format like 'yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss', e.g. your date `2012-10-11 07:00`, would be interpretted as 11th October by some cultures, and 10th November by others.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle of why not use yyyy-mm-dd dates](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/053eb6/1)**

Comment: +1, good answer and good advice. Here is your sqlfiddle comparing the results using yyyy-mm-dd with yyyymmdd http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/053eb6/1

Comment: @Lamak Thanks, I've updated the link in the answer with yours as it is more complete.

Comment: Amazing, thank you both guys, you've saved me some headache! Kudos! =0)